# Unable to connect to a remote JVM

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I'm working on a Java 10 application that uses an embedded Jetty server to provide control from a local network, and I'm attempting to connect to the JVM and failing.  It's running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop.

My startup script has the following lines:

```
java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.library_path=${LIB_PATH} -classpath ${CP} -jar ${APP_DIR}/app.jar
```

I have ufw on the system, and I've verified that the port is open. My output from ufw status includes:

```
8000 ALLOW Anywhere
8000 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere
```

In IntelliJ, my debug configuration is

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000
```

When I try to connect, I get an error message that the connection is refused.

with the IP of the machine in the config's address box.

Looking at the output of netstat -l, I see the following:

```
tcp 0 0 localhost:8000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

Does this mean that the debugger is only listening for connection on the localhost?  Do I need to do something to have it listen on a network?

Answer (score 3):

So I found the answer fairly quick.  I needed to modify the line I use for the server so that it reads:

```
java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:8000,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.library_path=${LIB_PATH} -classpath ${CP} -jar ${APP_DIR}/app.jar
```

So that is listens on all interfaces.